# having condition on result of a subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, mysql-error-1054, ifnull

i am trying to run a query like this

```
SELECT a, b , c, (SELECT INNULL(x,y)) as mycol WHERE mycol < 400 ;
```

BUt it gives the error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'mycol' in 'where clause'
```

What would be the right way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's so in **MS SQL**, so I assume, that the same problem is in **MySQL**.

Try to change **WHERE** to **HAVING**. **WHERE** clause doesn't see your renamed columns.

**HAVING** is working the same way as WHERE, like (mycol < 400 AND a > 5).

**GROUP BY** should be before **HAVING**.

Check the examples in the link.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm

Comment: thanks but sorry i forgot to mention that i am also using a group by clause in this query which seems to break the having thing. And what would be the syntax ifthere are multiple conditions to be checked with having ?

Comment: I've edited my answer. If it's what you wanted, just mark it as answer.

Comment: thanks this worked in a small sample query, will check if it does in the bigger one in a while. Thanks a lot.

Comment: and don't forget to mark it as answer. Do this in your other questions, if you got the answer.

Comment: ok will do it but a bit confused . i clicked on the green tick icon alongside this answer. I guess that does it.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Also you can vote up an answer (or anything else) if you find it useful. Read the faq:)
http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

@hgulyan I doubt your answer. It is not the renaming that prevents one from using `WHERE` clause, rather it is the subquery. So lets say I have a query:

```
SELECT id as ID FROM user WHERE ID > 10;
```

This is going to work perfectly fine.
Now lets say I have one more query:

```
SELECT name, (SELECT id FROM user_detail WHERE user_id = 20) as ID FROM user WHERE ID > 19;
```

This particular query will produce error as:

> Unknown column ID

So, it's about using subquery and column aliases and not just column aliases.
Thus in this case you will have to use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.